# mongodb pipeline limit to 1

Tags: mongodb, pipeline

I am trying to limit the returning array to just 1, currently when I run this it shows me all the results under the added `season` How do I limit the season to return 1.

```
{
  'from': 'episode',
  'let': {
    'episodeId': '$_id'
  },
  'pipeline': [{
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": ["$show_id", "$$episodeId"]
      }
    }
  }, {
      "$sort": {
        "pubDate": -1
      }
  
    
    
    
  }],
  'as': 'season'
}
```

Basically all I need from the sub-array is the first season number in the picture below you can see it is season 3.

[image: season query]

when I add the limit to the pipeline I get "Stage must be a properly formatted document."

[image]

Comment: Does [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) helps?

Comment: No it turns it into an error @ray

Comment: Would you please show us your sample data and your complete working code through [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) so that we can see whether we can replicate your issue?

Comment: @ray if I knew how to use that site, and join two collections together using it I would be happy to show you the data.

What I can do is paste the resulting JSON above.

Comment: Here is my [trial](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EDdpCPgtxEU) to replicate your issue. It's working correctly. From your error message, I guess formatting your code may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
db.show.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "episode",
      "let": {
        "episodeId": "$_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            "$expr": {
              "$eq": [
                "$show_id",
                "$$episodeId"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "pubDate": -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ],
      "as": "season"
    }
  }
])
```

You would get the out put as

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "season": [
      {
        "_id": 2,
        "pubDate": ISODate("2021-08-04T00:00:00Z"),
        "show_id": 1
      }
    ],
    "show": 1
  }
]
```